# Subclassing QSqlTableModel to setup database

Tags: qt, qsqltablemodel, qsqldatabase

I'm trying to subclass QSqlTableModel so that the constructor will set up the database that is needed for the model.

My code looks something along the lines of:

```
MyClass::myClass( QObject* parent, QSqlDatabase data )
    :QSqlTableModel(parent, data)
{
    auto db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if( !db.open() )
    {
        //Some debug info
    }
    if( !database().isOpen() )
    {
        // Some debug info that is called
    }
    qDebug() << database().connectionName();
    qDebug() << db.connectionName();
}
```

Then the constructor will output:
""
"qt_sql_default_connection"

Why are the two databases not both connected to the default connection?

Answer (score 1):

[QSqlDatabase::addDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase):

> Warning: If you add a connection with the same name as an existing
>   connection, the new connection replaces the old one. If you call this
>   function more than once without specifying connectionName, the default
>   connection will be the one replaced.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I wanted, however it seems the default connection is never made when calling QSqlDatabase().

Comment: If you want those two to be connected to the default connection name, you need to do this: `auto db = QSqlDatabase::database();`.

Comment: But in order to get it to access a SQLite database I need to use addDatabase(as per my example), this also connects to the default database, the problem is that apparently using `myclass(this,QSqlDatabase::database())` doesn't create a database with the default connection, but just one with an invalid database.

Comment: I told you to change one exact line. Why on earth, would you change anything else? You add database **once** and then you use `QSqlDatabase::database` in order to access this opened database any time after that.

Comment: Because I want the subclassed class to make sure a SQLite database is used and set up, not the user. But maybe I should just add the addDatabase into either the initialization or the default argument...

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple once a discussion had cleared out what was actually needed.
In the declaration, instead of using
`myClass( QObject* parent = nullptr, QSqlDatabase data = QSqlDatabase::database() );` I just  needed to use
`myClass( QObject* parent = nullptr, QSqlDatabase data = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" ) );`
Now the default option is to open a SQLite database, and if you want, you can provide another database.
Thanks to Amartel for a fruitfull diskussion